# created two plots that share x axis: second plot is cut off

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, overlay, axis

I have created a figure by creating a txin x axis with
`axs2[a] = axs[a].twinx()`
one plot is a contour plot and the other is some data points overlayed on the contour plot; however the datapoints are confined to the bounds of the plot. Is there any way to have the datapoints continue outside?

[image]

some more code for context

```
num_pulses = 2
axs2 = [0,1]
for x in range(num_pulses):
    time1 = data.epocs.Pu1_.onset[pulse]+delay_offset
    time2 = data.epocs.Pu1_.onset[pulse]+delay_offset+0.02
    t1=int(time1* data.streams.Raw1.fs)
    t = int(time2* data.streams.Raw1.fs) # int rounds it to the nearest integer
    index3 = x*100
    index4 = (x+1)*100
    im = axs[x].contourf(time_Raw1[t1:t], list(reversed(range(100))), csd_matrix[index3:index4,:], levels=levels, cmap=cmap)
    axs[x].yaxis.set_ticklabels([0,150,300,450,600,750])
    axs[x].set_xlabel('time(s)')
    axs[x].set_ylabel('Y(um)')
    axs[x].spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    axs[x].spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    axs[x].spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
    for b in range(16):
        axs2[x] = axs[x].twinx()
        if b<=8:
            channel_data = ((data_allchannels[b,t1:t]*1e6)/15)+(8-b)*46.875
        else:
            channel_data = ((data_allchannels[b,t1:t]*1e6)/15)-(b-8)*46.875
        axs2[x].plot(time_Raw1[t1:t],channel_data, color='k')
        axs2[x].set_ylim(-325,325)
        axs2[x].yaxis.set_visible(False)
        axs2[x].spines['right'].set_visible(False)
        axs2[x].spines['top'].set_visible(False)
        axs2[x].spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
```

Example of what I'm going for. From: https://journals.physiology.org/doi/pdf/10.1152/jn.00138.2013
[image]

Thanks!

Update: user in comments gave me the solution, thanks!

Comment: `ax.plot(..., clip_on=False)`.  You may also want to expand your ylimits.

Comment: Hey this worked, thank you!